# splitting string using switch afterwards

Tags: java, string, split

I'm currently porting a VB project to java and encountered a problem I'm stuck with.

I'm receiving a string which looks like the following:

```
HOST: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEFAULT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
OS: LINUX
ID: az150
LIB: eth15
```

newline at the end of each output, space after ":"
I'd like to split those strings and use a switch case afterwards. Not sure if the order stays the same all the time.

the switch case would look something like this:

```
switch(aString)
{
case "HOST":
   String host = HOST Value (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx);
   do something with it
   break;
...

default:
  break;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: just split according to `:\\s+` regex.

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Comment: @ Avinash Raj: will try that
@ Stultuske: sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm curious how to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: one thing I forgot to mention: It's possible one key doesn't have a value (e.g HOST: ). if I split using the :\\s+ regex wouldn't a key get assigned to a value by mistake?

Comment: In that case, I suggest you split by "\n" to separate it into lines and process each one separately with the :\\s+ regex.

Comment: thanks I think that got me into the right direction !

Answer (score 0):

The `String.split()` method is able to solve the problem and even no regular expression is needed.

Suggest you have a string like

```
String string = "HOST: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\n"
        + "DEFAULT: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\n"
        + "OS: LINUX\n"
        + "ID: az150\n"
        + "LIB: eth15";
```

then you can get a key-value line as follows

```
String[] lines = str.split("\n");
```

for each line in the array, key and value could be achieved like

```
String[] entry = s.split(":");
String key = entry[0];
String value = entry[1].trim(); // omit whitespace
```

then you can put the key-value pair anywhere you want, such as `Map`, `Property`, `Config`, etc. And then the switch sentence will work well. You can also check whether the value is empty before using it since the value might contain nothing.